# Inverse $D$ operators question

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, exponential-function, differential-operators

> Find $$\dfrac 1 {D^2+6D+9}e^{-3x}$$

So I am new to the topic of $2$nd order linear ordinary differential equations and on $d$-operators. I attempted the question below and am I not supposed to just replace $D$ with $-3$? That would give me $\frac{1}{0}$, which makes me wrong. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to solve for $y(x)$ once continuously differentiable and piecewise twice differentiable with $y(x)=0$ for $x<0$ and for $x\ge 0$
$$
(D+3)^2y(x)=e^{-3x}\iff (e^{3x}y(x))''=1
\\~\\
\implies e^{3x}y(x)=\frac{x^2}2u(x)
$$
where $u(x)$ is the unit jump from $0$ to $1$ at $x=0$.

Comment: I see. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

$$y_p=\dfrac 1 {(D^2+6D+9)}e^{-3x}$$
Write the operator as:
$$y_p=\dfrac 1 {(D+3)^2}e^{-3x}$$
Apply the rule
$$y_p=\dfrac 1 {f(D)}e^{ax}C(x)=e^{ax}\dfrac 1 {f(D+a)}C(x)$$
Here $C(x)=1$
So that you have;
$$y_p=e^{-3x}\dfrac 1 {D^2}1$$
$$y_p=e^{-3x}\dfrac 1 D (x+c_1)=e^{-3x}\left(\dfrac {x^2}{2}+c_1x+c_2\right)$$